# Moving Span Tag Animations

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I wanted to make something similar to a textreader, where I start with this sentence:

```
<p> <span> This is some </span> text that I want to write </p>
```

Then move to this sentence:

I've set a css style for the paragraph and span as follows:

```
p { color: black } span { color:red }
```

And I'd like to now transition the color from black to red as the span is highlighted. I'm currently moving the span tag by modifying the innerHTML of the page, and I believe that is causing the animation to avoid triggering.

Does anybody have any ideas as to how I could get the transition to trigger, without reanimating all of the red text.

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  newText = "<p> <span> This is some text that I want</span>  to write </p>"
  ptag = document.querySelector('p')
  ptag.innerHTML = newText
}, 1000)
```

```css
p{ color: black } 
span{ color:red }
```

```html
<p> <span> This is some </span> text that I want to write </p>
```

Comment: I did consider surrounding everything with span tags, but there is a large body of text here, would this be slow?

Answer (score 0):

I created a css animation to fade in the new span text from black to red, but one of the problems i had was that it would also fade in the existing span red text. So to fix that i introduced two span classes. One called complete and one called new. The animation is only applied to new.

So as you append new html text, the last `new` span will need to be added to the `complete` span, before you add the next `new` span, etc.

http://codepen.io/partypete25/pen/YWJQQB

```
function update(){
  newText = "<p> <span class='complete'> This is some text</span><span class='new'> that I want</span>  to write </p>"
  ptag = document.querySelector('p')
  ptag.innerHTML = newText
}


setTimeout(function(){ update() }, 1000);

p {
  color:black;
}
span.complete {
  color:red;
}
span.new {
  animation: color-change 2s linear 1 forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes color-change {
    0% { color: black; }
    100% { color: red; }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was initially going to go for a very similar solution, but if I want to animate each word in one-by-one, it becomes slightly intractable to do. Because you'd need to start a second animation (potentially) before the first one is complete.